# How to call a macro whenever the margins change?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to monitor the values of the two margins so that a macro is called whenever the margins are changed? Like displaying a message box which reads "Margins have changed!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has no capacity to trap events such as page layout changes.

Comment: So why the downvote? Is the answer unclear, not useful (not being what you wanted to hear doesn't make it 'not useful'), incomplete or inaccurate?